# Почему появляется ошибка "Call to a member function addPlayer() on null"?

Tags: php, классы

Обращаюсь к функции addPlayer. Она в первый раз срабатывает без ошибки, а на втором обращении появляется эта ошибка: "Call to a member function addPlayer() on null".

```
    $tournamentA = new Tournament("tournament", "1999.12.12");
$tournamentA
    ->addPlayer( (new Player("Player 1"))->setCity("city") )
    ->addPlayer( (new Player("Player 2"))->setCity("city") )
    ->addPlayer( (new Player("Player 3"))->setCity("city") )
    ->addPlayer( (new Player("Player 4"))->setCity("city") );
```

Функция из этого класса:

```
  class Tournament{
    
    private $name;
    private $date;
    private $player = [];
    
    function __construct($name, $date = null){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->date = $date??date('Y.m.d', strtotime('+1 day'));
    }
    
    public function addPlayer($player){
        $this->player[] = $player;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дак ты из метода ведешь новую стрелку, так не делается просто так, у тебя метод ничего не возвращает (никакой объект) что бы снова вызвать после него метод. Придется каждый раз писать $tournamentA->addPlayer( (new Player("Player N"))->setCity("city") );

Comment: Этот кусок кода как раз дали в задании. Я думал, что это нормально так писать по синтаксису. Видимо не норма. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно попробовать в методе addPlyaer в конце написать return $this; Возможно вернется тот же объект и тогда можно будет вызывать после метода снова метод этого объекта. Не помню как этот конвейер реализуется, вроде бы именно так ) А ошибка так и пишет тебе, что ты с Null якобы пытаешься вызвать метод, ну я так понимаю, ведь прошлый метод ничего не вернул )

Comment: Так тоже заработало. Ну или как минимум не появилось ошибок)
Спасибо большое)

Comment: @nx4n что значит "возможно вернется"? типа может быть и не вернется, или возможно, другой, и ли что ?

Comment: @teran В зависимости от настроения интерпретатора

Comment: Я почитал, и всё верно. Если прописать return $this; , то это будет ссылка на экземпляр класса. То есть код выше заработает правильно.

Comment: @teran, а ты дальше почитай просто что я пишу, а именно: "Не помню как этот конвейер реализуется, вроде бы именно так )", по тому и написано - возможно. Точно не помню, просто логичную идею предложил.

Comment: @nx4n так а чего тут помнить то? метод на экземпляре вызывается, чтобы продолжить цепочку надо экземпляр текущий и вернуть. тут помнить нечего, понимать надо что происходит. В общем мой коммент был к тому, чтобы спровоцировать вас подумать, что там происходит и почему так, а не придирка.

Comment: @teran, я понимаю что происходит, просто не помню как точно вернуть объект, ну уже вспомнил )) в плане синтаксиса, по тому и написал что Возможно, имея ввиду: возможно этот код вернёт объект )